# dll using issue in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, bouncycastle

I'm trying to use Bouncy Castel dll in my project. When I add it to my references I can't use it and when I write this code:

```
using BouncyCastle.Crypto;
```

I face with this error:
`The type or namespace name 'BouncyCastle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked it Micheal, you should write this:

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
```

instead of:

```
using BouncyCastle.Crypto;
```